# What is wrong with this proof of the Cauchy mean value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, solution-verification, proof-explanation

What is wrong with this proof of the Cauchy mean value theorem?

> **False Proof.** The mean value theorem applies to $f$ on $[a, b]$, so there exists $c \in (a, b)$ with
> $$
> f'(c) = \frac{f(b)−f(a)}{b−a}.
> $$
> The mean value theorem also applies to $g$ on $[a, b]$, so there exists $c \in (a, b)$ with
> $$
> g'(c) = \frac{g(b)−g(a)}{b−a}.
> $$
> Thus,
> $$
> \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} 
> = \frac{f(b) − f(a)}{b−a} 
> \cdot \frac{b-a}{g(b) − g(a)} 
> = \frac{f(b) − f(a)}{g(b) − g(a)}.
> $$

I think this may be false as it is assumed that both functions $f$ and $g$ have a common point $c$ such that this works, but I'm not sure. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> I think this may be false as it is assumed that both functions $f$ and $g$ have a common point $c$ such that this works, but I'm not sure.

Of course. For clarity you should say: there is $c\in (a,b)$ such that

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

and there is $d\in (a,b)$ such that

$$g'(d)=\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}$$

$c$ and $d$ may and often are different elements of $(a,b)$ interval.